# Toggle row independently of others in an {{#each}} - Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I've got this chunk of code in my controller to output everything I'd like to in the first row. The second row is going to be available upon a click action. However, I'm trying to make it so that when I click any row shown, it'll only display the 2nd row that given row. Not the 2nd row of all the others.

This is in my template.

```
{{#each chosenSomething as |something|}}
   <tr class='main' {{action 'toggleHelp'}}>
     <td>{{something.this}}</td>
     <td>{{something.that}}</td>
     <td>{{something.hey}}</td>
     <td>{{something.you}}</td>
   </tr>
   {{#if isDisplay}}
     <tr class='help'>
       <td class='instruction'></td>
       <td class='video'></td>
     </tr>
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

This is my JS for the action.

```
toggleHelp() {
    this.toggleProperty('isDisplay');
},
```

I know how I would approach this using jQuery, but I'd like to know the Ember way of doing such action. I thought about including index, but unsure how it should be written.

Comment: I think the question currently sounds more complex than it is. Do you just want to toggle the help row on click? - and this happens independently of any other rows' state?

Comment: I'm 100% sure it's worded more complicated than it is. Yes, that is correct. I need it to toggle independently from all other rows shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest making a component and handing the toggle within.

https://ember-twiddle.com/e6ccad3d2ffdc4a9d627db12a1317fa5?openFiles=templates.components.toggle-thing.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.toggle-thing.hbs

```
// toggle-thing.hbs
<header {{action 'toggleAnswer'}}>
    {{data.question}}
</header>

{{#if open}}
  <footer>
    {{data.answer}}
  </footer>
{{/if}}
```

```
// toggle-thing.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  // tagName: 'tr', // or whatever if you like
  // classNames: ['thing', 'row', 'etc'], // smooth out the template a bit later...
  open: false, // default
  actions: {
    toggleAnswer() {
      this.toggleProperty('open');
      console.log( this.get('open') );
    },
  },
});
```

```
// application.hbs or wherever you want to list the things
<ul class='thing-list'>
  {{#each model as |thing|}}
    <li class='thing'>
      {{toggle-thing data=thing}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

has a 'thing' model and is pulling in some question answers to the model hook for example.

```
import Ember from 'ember';

var data = [
  {
    question: "How to be funny",
    answer: "Stand on your head",
  },
  {
    question: "How to be smart",
    answer: "Just listen more often.",
  },
];

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model() {
    return data;
  },

});
```

The Ember guide has a toggle example: https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.13.0/tutorial/simple-component/

Answer (score 0):

Augment each element of `chosenSomething` to include the open/close state.
You'll then be able to have:

```
{{#each chosenSomething as |something|}}
  <tr class='main' {{action 'toggleHelp' something}}>
    <td>{{something.this}}</td>
    <td>{{something.that}}</td>
    <td>{{something.hey}}</td>
    <td>{{something.you}}</td>
  </tr>
  {{#if something.isDisplay}}
  <tr class='help'>
   <td class='instruction'></td>
   <td class='video'></td>
  </tr>
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

and the JS:

```
toggleHelp(something) {
    Ember.set(something, 'isDisplay', !something.isDisplay);
}
```

If you don't want to modify the original data, you can have a computed property generate the appropriate data such as:

```
chosenSomethingWithState() {
    return (this.get('chosenSomething') || []).map((item)=>{isDisplay:false, item})
}.property('chosenSomething')
```

and adjust the template accordingly